# A C function call that returns proper value but destination variable gets wrong

Tags: c, cmake, gtk, cairo

I am writing a library for producing charts from numerical data, it uses `cairo` and is meant to use code conventions similar to that library.

The problem was: A `C` function appears to return the value I expected, I saw it by means of `printf` just before `return`. But the destination variable gets assigned a different value, that is constant, event though the funtion return different values.

I would appreciate you if you are insterested in this question, and you can see the code for the two problematic functions in:

- https://github.com/exocode/slope/blob/master/slope/xymetrics.c
  lines 40 and 48.
- and the are called in
  https://github.com/exocode/slope/blob/master/slope/xydata.c
  line 65.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, seems to be due to the implicit declaration of those functions.

You need to include `slope/xymetrics.h` in `xydata.c` to get  the forward declarations for those functions `slope_xymetrics_map_x()` and `slope_xymetrics_map_y()`.

Comment: Thank you, this was the simple and direct answer. Now I don't know how this was compiling since the function was not declared. now the test program produces a beaultiful sine curve. The compiler knew where was the function to call it, but not to get the return value. This is realy strange